# Perform check on lists

Tags: python, list, loops, testing

I have 2 lists:

```
main_voltages = [5.5, 15.7, 28.5]
limit_list = [[5,10], [15,20], [25,30]]
```

I have to perform a check to see if 5.5 is in range of 5 to 10, if 15.7 is in range of 15 to 20 and 28.5 is in range of 25 to 30.
How should I make it happen without hardcoding anything? I ponder a lot over some functions but couldn't get the exact way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way using [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#ziphttps://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip):

```
>>> main_voltages = [5.5, 15.7, 28.5]
>>> limit_list = [[5,10], [15,20], [25,30]]
>>> result = [b[0] <= a <= b[1] for (a, b) in zip(main_voltages, limit_list)]
>>> result
[True, True, True]
```

Or as @ovgolovin pointed out, you can unpack the elements in the `limit_list` and do:

```
result = [a <= value <= b for (value, (a, b)) in zip(main_voltages, limit_list)]
```

Comment: +1 Though I would unpack b as well (meaning `result = [b[0] <= a <= b[1] for (a, b) in zip(main_voltages, limit_list)]` -> `result = [a <= value <= b for (value, (a, b)) in zip(main_voltages, limit_list)]`)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) and [all](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) to check each `ele` in `main_voltages` is within the range  `limit_list[ind][0]` and `limit_list[ind][1]` which corresponds to `element 0` and `element 1` in each sublist in the `limit_list`:

```
all(limit_list[ind][0] <= ele <= limit_list[ind][3] for ind,ele in enumerate(main_voltages))
```